# How to retrieve class instance using one attribute

Tags: java

I have a class Item, with each item there is a unique identifier which is associated with it. Is it feasible to retrieve the entire Item instance based on the unique identifier. That is, I want to use the unique identifier as the key.

```
 class Item{
     int id;
     String name;
     Date d;
 }
```

Now based on id, I want to retrieve its name and date. Is there some way to do so?

First I store the class instance..using a constructor, now based on some previously stored instance, given id. I want to retrieve the entire instance

Comment: first i store the class instance..using a constructor...now based on some previously stored instance..given id...i want to retrieve the entire instance

Comment: when you use the constructor, where does that newly created object live?  That is the place you have to search.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a HashMap like this.

```
HashMap<Integer, Item> itemMap = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
```

And just do something like,

```
itemMap.put(itemInstance.id, itemInstance);
```

Or maybe even an `ArrayList<Item>` and create a getter method that loops through the `ArrayList` for that specific id.

In any case, you're going to have create some type of collection.

Comment: And that map must be static, since it is common for all instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing a class instance with a container that searches for a class instances.

Strictly speaking, there is nothing about the class's id which will help you find that class instance.  However, in a collection of class instances, you could simply iterate the objects, checking each one's id.  All of this is completely dependent on your collection's type.

Answer (score 0):

> First I store the class instance..using a constructor, now based on some previously stored instance, given id. I want to retrieve the entire instance

There is no intrinsic support for this in Java.

You could implement it yourself something like this:

```
public class Item {
   private static HashMap<Integer, Item> all = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
   private final int id;
   private String name;
   private Datedate;

   public Item(int id, String name, Date date) {
       this.id = id; this.name = name; this.date = date;
       synchronized (all) {
           all.put(id, this);
       }
   }

   // getters and setters

   public static getInstance(int id) {
       synchronized (all) {
           return all.get(id);
       }
   }
}
```

**HOWEVER ...** this is a massive storage leak.  Every `Item` instance ever created is always reachable via the `all` static, and therefore cannot be garbage collected.  In a lot of cases, this is enough to make this approach non-viable.